# Failure to compile incomplete types; circular dependencies

Tags: c++, g++, circular-dependency

Hi am having problems compiling some code, I have a situation where A depends and B depends on A. I have put forward declarations but I keep getting the problems.

```
In file included from src/MemoWriteContext.h:7:0,
                  from src/MemoWriteContext.cpp:1:
src/MemoContext.h:29:20: error: field ‘memoWriteContext’ has incomplete type
```

MemoContext.h

```
#ifndef MEMOCONTEXT_H_
#define MEMOCONTEXT_H_

#include "sqlite/SqliteDb.h"
#include "Context.h"
#include "MemoWriteContext.h"

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

namespace bbs
{
    class MemoWriteContext;

    class MemoContext : public Context
    {
    public:
        //'structors
        MemoContext(const std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Context> > &_contexts,
                    sqlitecpp::SqliteDb &_sqliteDb);
        ~MemoContext();

    protected:
        //when called write the data back to the user
        void performAction(const std::string &data, std::shared_ptr<UserAgent> agent);

    private:
        MemoWriteContext memoWriteContext;
    }; //class memocontext
}

#endif  // MEMOCONTEXT_H_
```

MemoWriteContext.h

```
#ifndef MEMOWRITECONTEXT_H_
#define MEMOWRITECONTEXT_H_

#include "Context.h"
#include "sqlite/SqliteDb.h"
#include "sqlite/PreparedStmt.h"
#include "MemoContext.h"

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

namespace bbs
{
    class MemoContext; //forward decl

    class MemoWriteContext : public Context
    {
    public:
        //'structors
        MemoWriteContext(const std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Context> > &_contexts,
                        MemoContext &_memoContext, sqlitecpp::SqliteDb &_sqliteDb);
        ~MemoWriteContext();

    protected:
        //when called write the data back to the user
        virtual void performAction(const std::string &data, std::shared_ptr<UserAgent> agent);
        virtual void onReceiveUserAgent(std::shared_ptr<UserAgent> agent);
    private:
        MemoContext &memoContext; //parent;
        sqlitecpp::SqliteDb &sqliteDb;
        sqlitecpp::PreparedStmt writeMemoStmt;  
        sqlitecpp::PreparedStmt findAgentIdStmt;    
    };

    enum class MemoWriteState : char
    {
        USERNAME=0,
        MESSAGE,
        CONFIRM
    };  

    class MemoWriteAgentData : public ContextAgentData
    {
    public:
        MemoWriteState state;
        int userId;
        std::string message;    
    }; //class Memo Write Agent data

}

#endif  // MEMOWRITECONTEXT_H_
```

[Full source here.](http://dobson156.dyndns.org/gitweb/?p=bbs.git;a=tree;f=src;h=7bf4245f5215b8c269bb313748ae09af95880a49;hb=HEAD)

Comment: this question has really nothing to do with c++0x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your only problem is that `MemoWriteContext.h` has `#include "MemoContext.h"`.  The context only requires a reference which can use the forward declaration.  But if you happen to include `MemoWriteContext.h` *first* it will then bring in `MemoContext.h` *before* it actually declares `class MemoWriteContext`.  That will then use the forward declaration of `class MemoWriteContext` and fail.  You can even see the ordering in your error message.

Just remove that `#include` or at least reverse the order of the includes in `MemoWriteContext.cpp` (since each `.h` including the other effectively reverses them back).

Comment: This worked perfectly, now compiles and I get to keep stack semantics. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
class MemoWriteContext;
```

Is a forward declaration. It's an "incomplete type", and therefore cannot be instantiated.

The reason is that a C++ compiler must know the size of any type that has to be instantiated. Incomplete types have no size.

By the way, you can do this:

```
MemoWriteContext * ptr;
```

Because you actually declare a pointer, and pointers have a known size.

If you want to avoid dynamic allocations, then you'll have to fully declare the type by including `MemoWriteContext.h` and removing the forward declaration.

Comment: Yeah but I really don't want a pointer to the other type I just want it on the stack if possible. Is there another way around this?

Comment: Each has access to the others header. I have put the forward dec's in a bid to get around the cirular dependancy however this hasn't solved it. I really would prefer not to use for dynamic memory if we can at all help it. Thanks